# Kaa Admin panel becomes not reachable every now and then on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kaa

Not sure why every now and then the kaa admin panel becomes not reachable from the sandbox installation on AWS. Sometimes I change the admin port from 8080 to something else and restart the kaa node then I am able to open the admin panel. But again after a day it again becomes unreachable. What could be the root cause of such an erratic behaviour?

Comment: Could you, please, describe what you've done step-by-step?

Comment: I simply downloaded Kaa Sandbox to AWS from Kaa's home page. Straight forward installation. But It might be due to the reason that I am using T2 micro instance which might cause this due to resource constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the T2 micro instance seems the only solution for now until I enhance the server config.